# Very Big XML query to insert into CLOB field

Tags: xml, string, oracle, insert, procedure

thanks for your help; i need to query this XML structure to insert the records into a CLOB field, but SQL Developer sends me this error in the query:

Note: the XML string is very very very long, those three records are only for example.

```
ORA-01704: literal de cadena demasiado largo
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
       Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
Error en la línea: 4, columna: 1

with t as
(
select XMLTYPE(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XMLTitulares.xsd" generated="2017-09-28T12:56:19">
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>949</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INCAN</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. ANTELMO ABELARDO MENESES GARCÍA</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Antelmo Abelardo Meneses García,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INCAN.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Dir. 56-28-04-01, 56-28-04-02 y 56-28-04-03, Conm. 56-28-04-00 Ext. 44001, 4402 y 4403</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Av. San Fernando No. 22, Torre de Hospitalización, 4° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Av. San Fernando y Calz. de Tlalpan,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Sección XVI</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Tlalpan</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>14080</CP><E-MAIL>menesesabelardo@gmail.com</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><DENOMINACIÓN>Secretaría de Salud</DENOMINACIÓN><SIGLAS_CS>101</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-06-21T13:55:40</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 7:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 8:00 a 16:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.incan.edu.mx#http://www.incan.edu.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2013-08-17T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2018-08-16T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
</dataroot>'
) as xml_
from dual
)
select XMLRoot(s.column_value, VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8').getClobVal()  as "CLOB FIELD"
from t, table(xmlsequence(EXTRACT(t.xml_, '/dataroot/XMLTitulares')))s;
```

I would appreciate your help if you also help me, to show me how to do the insertion procedure. Thank you a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may swicht to PL/SQL to define al long literal, as proposed e.g. [here](http://ozzieeu.blogspot.co.at/2011/11/ora-01704-string-literal-too-long.html)

**SQL Fails**

```
select XMLTYPE(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XMLTitulares.xsd" generated="2017-09-28T12:56:19">
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>949</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INCAN</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. ANTELMO ABELARDO MENESES GARCÍA</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Antelmo Abelardo Meneses García,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INCAN.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Dir. 56-28-04-01, 56-28-04-02 y 56-28-04-03, Conm. 56-28-04-00 Ext. 44001, 4402 y 4403</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Av. San Fernando No. 22, Torre de Hospitalización, 4° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Av. San Fernando y Calz. de Tlalpan,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Sección XVI</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Tlalpan</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>14080</CP><E-MAIL>menesesabelardo@gmail.com</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><DENOMINACIÓN>Secretaría de Salud</DENOMINACIÓN><SIGLAS_CS>101</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-06-21T13:55:40</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 7:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 8:00 a 16:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.incan.edu.mx#http://www.incan.edu.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2013-08-17T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2018-08-16T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
</dataroot>'
) as xml_
from dual;



SQL-Fehler: ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
```

**But PL/SQL works**

```
drop table myTab;
create table myTab
(myXML XMLType);



DECLARE 
  myClob CLOB;
BEGIN
  myClob := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="XMLTitulares.xsd" generated="2017-09-28T12:56:19">
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>949</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INCAN</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. ANTELMO ABELARDO MENESES GARCÍA</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE CANCEROLOGÍA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Antelmo Abelardo Meneses García,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INCAN.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Dir. 56-28-04-01, 56-28-04-02 y 56-28-04-03, Conm. 56-28-04-00 Ext. 44001, 4402 y 4403</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Av. San Fernando No. 22, Torre de Hospitalización, 4° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Av. San Fernando y Calz. de Tlalpan,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Sección XVI</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Tlalpan</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>14080</CP><E-MAIL>menesesabelardo@gmail.com</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><DENOMINACIÓN>Secretaría de Salud</DENOMINACIÓN><SIGLAS_CS>101</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-06-21T13:55:40</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 7:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja de 8:00 a 16:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.incan.edu.mx#http://www.incan.edu.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2013-08-17T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2018-08-16T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
 <XMLTitulares><ID>72</ID><ORDEN>7</ORDEN><SIGLAS>INAPESCA</SIGLAS><DEPENDENCIA>INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</DEPENDENCIA><TITULAR>DR. PABLO ARENAS FUENTES</TITULAR><CARGO>DIRECTOR GENERAL DEL INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE LA PESCA</CARGO><CCP_TITULAR>Dr. Pablo Arenas Fuentes,</CCP_TITULAR><CCP_CARGO>Director General del INAPESCA.</CCP_CARGO><TELEFONOSD>Conm. 38-71-95-00 y 38-71-95-02 Ext. 55003</TELEFONOSD><DIRECCIÓN>Pitágoras No. 1320, 8° Piso,</DIRECCIÓN><ENTRE_LAS_CALLES>Entre Miguel Laurent y Pilares,</ENTRE_LAS_CALLES><COLONIA>Santa Cruz Atoyac</COLONIA><MUNICIPIO>Benito Juárez</MUNICIPIO><ESTADO>Ciudad de México</ESTADO><CP>03310</CP><E-MAIL>pablo.arenas@inapesca.gob.mx</E-MAIL><CSO>0</CSO><OICEXT_ID>SAGARPA</OICEXT_ID><SIGLAS_CS>085</SIGLAS_CS><FECHA>2017-02-09T14:28:30</FECHA><OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR>La documentación se recibe en Oficialía de Partes, Planta Baja, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_TITULAR><OBSERVACIONES_CI>La documentación la reciben en el Mezzanine en Oficialía de Partes, de 9:00 a 15:00 y 16:00 a 18:00 hrs.</OBSERVACIONES_CI><TIPO>a esa entidad fiscalizada.</TIPO><Ruta_Titular>2</Ruta_Titular><PAGINA_DE_INTERNET>www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#http://www.inp.sagarpa.gob.mx#</PAGINA_DE_INTERNET><PInicio1>2015-01-16T00:00:00</PInicio1><Pfin1>2020-11-30T00:00:00</Pfin1><foraneo>0</foraneo><EntDept>F</EntDept><ccpSFP>Mtra. Arely Gómez González, Secretaria de la Función Pública.</ccpSFP><ACTUALIZADODEF>0</ACTUALIZADODEF></XMLTitulares>
</dataroot>';
insert into myTab (myXML)
select XMLTYPE(myClob) as xml_ 
from dual;
commit;
END;
/

select length(c.myxml.getClobVal()) from myTab c;

5229
```

So this works safely above 4000 characters, but is limited with length 32767.

You'll have to workaround for longer strings e.g. by splitting in chunks:

```
 select XMLTYPE(myClob||myClob2)
```

for extreme long documents you will probably choose to read them from file and pass it as bind variable.